# displaying on Sale items from specific categories

Tags: magento, categories

Is there a way to display the on sale products for certain categories. For example I am making landings pages at the moment for all of my Categories and I want them to display the products that are on sale in just that category.

I have searched for this but can only find how to display all on sale items by creating a new category with all sale items in then displaying that on a new CMS page.

If you can help thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On list page only check Product special price is exists or not, if special price is there get discount with calculation and display your product. Use below code for filter collection.

```
<?php $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('neq' => 0));?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have attribute `sale` assigned to products for specific category with values Yes = 1 / No = 2, then you could do something like below:

In your product collection filter the records by attribute

```
$YourCollection->addAttributeToFilter('sale', array('eq' => '1'));
```

This will display only those products which has attribute `sale` set to `Yes`.

Also make sure the attribute `sale` (and others that you want to list) have the flag **Use in product listing** set to **Yes**

Comment: i will try this and let you know how i get on, thank you for the response though.

Comment: i couldnt get this to work but did find a way to do it. To be honest it was most lily my coding ability rather than your answer as i am very new to PHP and magento. Thank you for responding though.

Comment: @AdamAllen facing the same issue...what did you do to achieve this?